# Resizing a XSLFChart

Tags: java, apache-poi, xslf

When creating a `XSLFChart` on a `XSLFSlide`, I can't seem to get the anchoring to work as intended.
I'm generate the chart as follows

```
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();
XSLFChart chart = ppt.createChart(slide);
slide.addChart(chart, new Rectangle(200, 200, 200, 200));
// Further styling and data
```

But when I open the Powerpoint, the chart is scrunched up in the top left corner, as if it was anchored with a `Rectangle` at (0, 0) with a height and width of 0. Creating the chart with the other overload of the function (`addChart(XSLFChart)`) also creates it in the corner, but with some height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the `XSLFChart` needs to be set in measurement unit English Metric Units `EMU`, not in points as for other anchors of `XSLFSimpleShape`. There is [org.apache.poi.util.Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html) to convert between different other units (points also) and `EMU`.

In your case:

```
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();
XSLFChart chart = ppt.createChart(slide);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200*Units.EMU_PER_POINT, 200*Units.EMU_PER_POINT, 200*Units.EMU_PER_POINT, 200*Units.EMU_PER_POINT);
slide.addChart(chart, rect);
```

Comment: That got it to work. Interesting that charts are so different with the rectangles they expect with no documentation to represent so.